# Starting MySQL ERROR! Couldn't find MySQL server (/usr/share/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe)

Tags: mysql

1、my system:CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) ;

2、my java :Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)；

3、my MySQL： MySQL-server-5.6.38-1.el7.x86_64.rpm；

before i install it this ,i had install once,

before i install it again,i had checked,

(1)rpm -qa | grep mariadb,

(2)rpm -qa | grep -i mysql,

(3)find / -name mysql,
i delete or remove all of it ,

then ,i download MySQL-server-5.6.38-1.el7.x86_64.rpm from mysql.com，

then i  install it ,rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.6.38-1.el7.x86_64.rpm,

then i start it ,service mysql start,

Starting MySQL ERROR! Couldn't find MySQL server (/usr/share/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe)

Comment: My guess is that your MySQL never started.

Comment: yes，never started,and  what should i do ? i can't find mysqld_safe in /usr/share/mysql, the directory /usr/share/mysql/bin is not exist

Comment: Check the logs.

Comment: thank you very much，let me see